# How can I use "insight"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I want to express that after a certain experience I have some new insights.  Does an insight come "into mind", or do you "gain/develop" insight? How is this best phrased?

Comment: Things generally come "to mind" rather than "into mind". "Insight" would seem to make sense as a thing to "come to mind", but it somehow doesn't really sound right to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Gain insight* is a very common (and rather generic) phrasing. Believe me, I know that, I tend to overuse it in academic writing ;-)

Other possible constructions include: “this experience provided me with insight into …”, “I developed a better insight into …”, “this intership offered plenty of insight into …”, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm also trying to write an academic paper! My writing is still a bit rusty after 15 years, and English is not my mother tongue